# Unable to cast - 'CDSRuntime.SandboxWorker.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper' to type ..WebProxyClient<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, xrm

I am trying to get access token from `IOrganizationService` inside custom workflow.

Below is the logic I'm using to retrieve IOrganisationService in custom workflow:

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
_organizationService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

I have tried getting [Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.securitytokenresponse.token?view=dynamics-general-ce-9#microsoft-xrm-sdk-client-securitytokenresponse-token) through `OrganizationServiceProxy` by below code:

```
var proxy = (OrganizationServiceProxy) _organizationService;
var token = proxy.SecurityTokenResponse.Token;
```

which is also resulting in the same error.

**What is the possible way here to get access token in this custom workflow?**

Comment: Interesting. Inside a workflow you're already authenticated. What do you plan to do with the token?

Comment: Actually the reason is I want to download the large file i.e. >4 MB in chunks and then merge it.

Comment: Using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/file-attributes#example-net-c-code-for-download-with-chunking

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Rather than trying to connect to the API from within a workflow, is there a way to download the file through the IOrganizationService? Have you tried just retrieving it as a regular column via `service.Retrieve()`?

Comment: I was curious, so I looked into it... You are right, [Retrieve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/file-attributes) doesn't work: _"Messages such as RetrieveRequest and RetrieveMultipleRequest cannot be used to download file column data."_

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to connect to the Web API from within a Workflow or Plugin. If anyone can confirm yes or no, that would be great. Assuming it's "no", I'd probably look into an [Azure aware plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/write-custom-azure-aware-plugin?view=op-9-1).  The plugin listener could connect via the Web API, download the file, and do whatever operation you need...

Comment: Thank you so much Aron, I will definitely give it an another look and will keep details posted here.